# Getting singular fit error on lmer model after standardizing the response variable

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, standardization, singular-matrix

I'm running a mixed model with the `lmer`function in R, and am running into an issue with singular fits. My dataset is comprised of 48,538 observations of sleep duration values (in hours) from 220 participants (identifier is `snapshot_id`) collected over the course of a year. If I run a baseline model using the raw sleep duration metrics, my model fits fine:

```
mod_RQ1_base <- lmer(adjusted_sleep_duration ~ (1|snapshot_id), REML = F, data=sleep_daily_summary_complete_year_meq_week, na.action = na.exclude)
jtools::summ(mod_RQ1_base, scale = TRUE, digits = 5)
```

[image: model summary output]

However, in my case, I want to build a model to predict the changes in sleep duration based on an individuals baseline (i.e. their mean sleep). To do so, I thought I would standardize the sleep duration metric by subtracting the mean sleep duration and dividing by the standard deviation of sleep duration for that participant. However, when I try to run the same baseline model with the standardized sleep duration, I get a singular fit error:

```
mod_RQ1_base <- lmer(standardized_adjusted_sleep_duration ~ (1|snapshot_id), REML = F, data=sleep_daily_summary_complete_year_meq_week, na.action = na.exclude)
jtools::summ(mod_RQ1_base, scale = TRUE, digits = 5)
```

[image]

I get the same error when I add other fixed-effect variables I am planning to test to the models as well, but as I'm running into this error already in the baseline model, I think there is a problem here I am not understanding.

My questions are as follows:

1. Am I getting this error because I normalized sleep duration by participant identifier (`snapshot_id`) and am adding a random intercept effect on `snapshot_id` as well?
2. Since I want to model what predicts variation sleep duration that are relative to each person's individual baseline, how can I do this realistically and also avoid the singular fit error using mixed models?

Any insight into why I'm getting this error just when I standardize the response (and why I'm not when I don't standardize the response), and how to model the data properly would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalizing the dependent variable as you have does not make sense. It would be one thing to take a regular z-score of it (based on the sample mean and standard deviation). Sometimes people do that to their predictors and outcome to get their coefficients into an effect size metric - 1 standard deviation increase in predictor is associated with XX standard deviation change in outcome.

The multilevel model was designed to analyze outcomes that, because of nesting or other non-nested grouping, have both within- and between-group variance. The proportion of variance that is within/between is quantified by the ICC as reported in your output. But the normalization you carried out removes all the individual variation at level 1 (person's standard deviation) and at between person variation at level 2 (their mean). So what is left over for the model to estimate?

Just to show that I can replicate your results using the sleepstudy data in `lme4`, I ran models where I transformed the outcome (Reaction) in the ways mentioned and ran so-called empty models.

First the Reaction variable in its raw metric:

```
library(lme4)
library(dplyr)
data("sleepstudy")
raw <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + (1|Subject), sleepstudy)
jtools::summ(raw)

MODEL INFO:
Observations: 180
Dependent Variable: Reaction
Type: Mixed effects linear regression 

MODEL FIT:
AIC = 1910.33, BIC = 1919.91
Pseudo-R² (fixed effects) = 0.00
Pseudo-R² (total) = 0.39 

FIXED EFFECTS:
---------------------------------------------------------
                      Est.   S.E.   t val.    d.f.      p
----------------- -------- ------ -------- ------- ------
(Intercept)         298.51   9.05    32.98   17.00   0.00
---------------------------------------------------------

p values calculated using Satterthwaite d.f.

RANDOM EFFECTS:
------------------------------------
  Group      Parameter    Std. Dev. 
---------- ------------- -----------
 Subject    (Intercept)     35.75   
 Residual                   44.26   
------------------------------------

Grouping variables:
---------------------------
  Group    # groups   ICC  
--------- ---------- ------
 Subject      18      0.39 
---------------------------
```

Next, the traditional z-score, using the sample mean and standard deviation:

```
sleepstudy <- sleepstudy %>% mutate(s_mn_reaction=mean(Reaction), s_sd_reaction=sd(Reaction), z_reaction=(Reaction-s_mn_reaction)/s_sd_reaction)

z <- lmer(z_reaction ~ 1 + (1|Subject), sleepstudy)

jtools::summ(z)
MODEL INFO:
Observations: 180
Dependent Variable: z_reaction
Type: Mixed effects linear regression 

MODEL FIT:
AIC = 467.16, BIC = 476.73
Pseudo-R² (fixed effects) = 0.00
Pseudo-R² (total) = 0.39 

FIXED EFFECTS:
-------------------------------------------------------
                    Est.   S.E.   t val.    d.f.      p
----------------- ------ ------ -------- ------- ------
(Intercept)         0.00   0.16     0.00   17.00   1.00
-------------------------------------------------------

p values calculated using Satterthwaite d.f.

RANDOM EFFECTS:
------------------------------------
  Group      Parameter    Std. Dev. 
---------- ------------- -----------
 Subject    (Intercept)     0.63    
 Residual                   0.79    
------------------------------------

Grouping variables:
---------------------------
  Group    # groups   ICC  
--------- ---------- ------
 Subject      18      0.39 
---------------------------
```

Note that the ICC is the same as in the raw metric model (good). The standard deviation of the random intercepts has changed because of the z-scoring, which could be good or bad depending on one's perspective. Personally, I like to keep dependent variables in their original metric.

Now for the results when I normalize Reaction in the same manner as you proposed:

```
sleepstudy <- sleepstudy %>% group_by(Subject) %>% mutate(mn_reaction = mean(Reaction), sd_reaction = sd(Reaction)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% mutate(p_z_reaction = (Reaction-mn_reaction)/sd_reaction) 

p_z <- lmer(p_z_reaction ~ 1 + (1|Subject), sleepstudy)
jtools::summ(p_z)

MODEL INFO:
Observations: 180
Dependent Variable: p_z_reaction
Type: Mixed effects linear regression 

MODEL FIT:
AIC = 501.31, BIC = 510.89
Pseudo-R² (fixed effects) = 0.00
Pseudo-R² (total) = 0.00 

FIXED EFFECTS:
---------------------------------------------------------
                     Est.   S.E.   t val.     d.f.      p
----------------- ------- ------ -------- -------- ------
(Intercept)         -0.00   0.07    -0.00   179.00   1.00
---------------------------------------------------------

p values calculated using Satterthwaite d.f.

RANDOM EFFECTS:
------------------------------------
  Group      Parameter    Std. Dev. 
---------- ------------- -----------
 Subject    (Intercept)     0.00    
 Residual                   0.95    
------------------------------------

Grouping variables:
---------------------------
  Group    # groups   ICC  
--------- ---------- ------
 Subject      18      0.00 
---------------------------
```

As you can see, all variation between groups is gone, or alternatively, through the by-person standardization, we removed all within-person variation in Reaction. Bottom line is that the normalization you proposed removes the very thing the multilevel model is designed to analyze.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, I realized that the normalization is redundant if I include the random effect on what I normalized on. Essentially, from my understanding now, mixed effects models with random effects on participant ID acts essentially as to create a separate regression model per participant, which is what I want, and in the case of separate regression models, normalization is unnecessary. Marking your question as best answer, as I agree completely.

Comment: Yes. Remember that the random effects model does this for the dependent variable. Your predictors might be occasion varying in which case I would suggest you consider including the person mean for each of your occasion varying predictors. This separates the predictor into within and between parts.